# What is best practice for securing access to GMail for an enterprise?

Tags: security, google-workspace, best-practices, gmail

Is there any way to restrict access to Gmail accounts from certain IP/MAC addresses ? For instance, can I setup Google Apps so that my users can access their GMail account from within the corporate firewall or from outside the firewall on a known machine, but not from a public browser or public machine.
Or what would be best practice to prevent unauthorized access to corporate GMail accounts?

Answer (score 2):

GMail has no IP or region restrictions. What you could do though is enable 2-step verification to add further protection?

This requires two steps in setting up, one at the domain level:

1. Go to your Google Apps administrator control panel.
2. Click the Advanced tools tab.
3. Under Authentication > 2-step verification, check Allow users to turn on 2-factor authentication.

And the other on a per user basis:

Settings -> Accounts and Import -> Change Account Settings -> Other Google account settings -> Using 2-step verification

NOTE: The users have to manually opt-in even if you have this enabled at the domain level.

Comment: Is there any way of restricting when a user would need to use 2 step vs not? otherwise my users will never put up with it.

Comment: Appears not. Also even if you "switch it on" at the domain level, your users still have to manually opt-in themselves. And if they are anything like my users, that just isn't going to happen. Link to Google help: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=184711